# android videoview error 1, -2147483648

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am getting error while playing video from asset folder and raw folder.
MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)
VideoView error 1, -2147483648.

I tried from asset folder as.

```
private String SrcPath = "file:///android_asset/aaa.mp4"; //also tried aaaa.mp3
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
vv.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
controller.setAnchorView(vv);
vv.setMediaController(controller);
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
```

and for raw folder i used URI as :

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.usecontentprovider/raw/aaa.mp4");
vv.setVideoURI(video);
```

I got the same error message in both cases.

Comment: Normally that error means that your device is not supporting the video format you are playing.

Comment: I am running my app on AVD and I tried on 5-6 AVD's of different configurations, still error was same. Can we play video in virtual devices?

Comment: Ah...... now try it in real device. You generally not get that error in real device unless any unknown format you are using.

Comment: ok I will try it on real device

Comment: Anyway, thanks for a quick reply

Comment: I found the solution as I am able to play video on virtual deice.I replaced the line                                                       
              Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.usecontentprovider/raw/aaa.mp4");

with

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.usecontentprovider/raw/"+R.raw.aaa);

And its working

Comment: Good that you found solution your self :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  found the solution as I am able to play video on virtual device.
I replaced the line

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.usecontentprovider/raw/aaa.mp4");
```

with

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.usecontentprovider/raw/"+R.raw.aaa);
```

And its working

Comment: how can play from url

Comment: so how is R.raw.aaa different from aaa.mp4?

Comment: @hariszaman `R.raw.aaa` is a resource ID (an int), while the string with `aaa.mp4` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use software like [avinaptic2](http://fsinapsi.altervista.org/) to get the video encoding information and make sure it matches the [supported media formats in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

A common problem I find is that videos are encoded with the wrong profiling. H.264 videos need to be encoded with Baseline level 3 or under to be played without errors or artifacts in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Using `R.raw` works fine but in some cases I still get the same error. Fortunately I found the solution to my problem: I had to call `videoView.start()` inside `onPrepare()`.

You can check the correct answer here:
[Android: 'Can't play this video'; MediaPlayer & VideoView Error 1 -38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005617/android-cant-play-this-video-mediaplayer-videoview-error-1-38)