# MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Trying to debug my application, I have found this error in the logcat.

When this happens, the application seems to display a black screen (when it should be playing a video). If I hit the home key (to exit without destroying the app in memory) then launch the application again, it starts displaying the video as normal.

What is this error code trying to tell me? I cannot seem to find any solid info on what it is. There are no matching results for the part of the code "-2147483648".

Comment: This is MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN with UNKNOWN reason. Usually it is an encoding problem, or a problem accessing the video file. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833537 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925859

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same error "-2147483648" by correcting my incomplete file path when setting the data source: myMediaPlayer.setDataSource("corrected file path here");