# Android: 'Can't play this video'; MediaPlayer & VideoView Error 1 -38

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I tried to play a video with the code below. However, I get the classic error of 'Can't play this video' pop-up at run time. I did my due diligence in searching the android literature and looking through other people's questions, but I can't seem to find the problem a) because no where in the documentation can I find the error code (1 ,-38) for MediaPlayer and b) my video meets the specifications required for android media formats (h.264 and MPEG-4). If anyone can help point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it! Thanks

```
private void startVideo() {
    Log.v(TAG, "videoUrl = " + mVideoUrl);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(mVideoUrl);
    mVideo = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.preview_videoView);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideo);
    mVideo.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideo.start();
}
```

These are the logs

```
10-07 21:08:38.529    9986-9986/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid V/﹕ videoUrl = http://files.parsetfss.com/2bb9a4a0-9f35-4124-a634-d2fa7f8b165e/tfss-ca535209-4b4c-4022-95b8-8f011ed41daf-High%20Knees.mp4
10-07 21:08:38.579   9986-10011/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-07 21:08:38.579   9986-10011/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5245c20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-07 21:08:38.609    9986-9986/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-07 21:08:39.582    9986-9986/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid D/MediaPlayer﹕ getMetadata
10-07 21:08:39.637    9986-9999/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
10-07 21:08:39.637    9986-9986/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)
10-07 21:08:39.637    9986-9986/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,-38
10-07 21:08:39.650   9986-10000/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
10-07 21:08:39.702    9986-9986/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)
10-07 21:08:39.702    9986-9986/com.trainwithtanya.hiitandroid D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,-38
```

Here is the video format 
http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll185/akhan007/mediaType_zpsjfvfdpto.png

Comment: can you tell me where is the video? you want to play

Comment: http://files.parsetfss.com/2bb9a4a0-9f35-4124-a634-d2fa7f8b165e/tfss-ca535209-4b4c-4022-95b8-8f011ed41daf-High%20Knees.mp4

Comment: plz refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806261/strange-behavior-of-android-videoview-cant-play-video

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you need call `mVideo.start();` inside `onPrepare`

```
mVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mVideo.start();
  }
});
```

Comment: my case .mp4 video failed